# Trying to setup a Cannon Image Class MF4880dw Printer

Tags: printing, canon

So for Christmas my Mother got a Cannon Image Class MF4880dw Printer. 
I have Ubuntu 12.03 setup on her Laptop. I'm trying to get this printer to work via WIFI. I had figured that network printers wouldn't require drivers..

I see that on [Cannon's website](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/printers_multifunction/black_white_laser_multifunction/imageclass_mf4880dw#DriversAndSoftware) there are not any drivers.

Is there any other way of using this printer or do I need drivers?

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsPrinters/CanonPrinters

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it printing, using the drivers for the [ImageCLASS MF4450](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/printers_multifunction/black_white_laser_multifunction/imageclass_mf4450#DriversAndSoftware).

However, it looks like scanning is not supported.